# How to define types of push notification in iOS?

Tags: ios, notifications, push

I'd like to define types of push notifications. Different actions are followed.

For example, the badge of tab A on receiving type A is updated and that of tab B on receiving type B is updated.

The current simple payload is as follows.
{"aps":{"alert":"nickname001."}}

How to define types of push notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one key value pair in your payload

For Example :

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "nickname001 just liked you!",
        "badge": 2
    },
    "action": 1
}
```

Then when receive push notification, just check and follow your requirement.

```
NSInteger page = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"action"] integerValue];
switch (page) {

    case 1:
        {
            //Update tab A - type A
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        {
            //Update tab B - type B
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
```

Also you can do it by nested keys and nested `switch-case` respectively…like :

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "nickname001 just liked you!",
        "badge": 2
    },
    "action": {
        "tab": 1,
        "type": "A"
    }         
}
```

and respectively

```
NSInteger page = [[[userInfo objectForKey:@“action”] objectForKey:@“tab”] integerValue];
switch (page) {

    case 1:
            {
                NSString *strType = [[[userInfo objectForKey:@"action"] objectForKey:@"type"] uppercaseString];
                if ([strType isEqualToString:@"A"]) {

                    // update type A
                }
                else {

                   // update type B
                }
        }
        break;

    case 2:
            {
    }
        break;

default:
        break;
```